# Parse Migration - How to migrate parse data to localhost mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, migration

I had been trying to migrate my parse data to localhost mongoDB but to no avail. There are a total of 12 steps as mentioned in https://parse.com/migration#database

I am currently still at step 1 and I had encountered some difficulties. I managed to set mongoDB on my computer (localhost). Then I went to my "app settings" in parse to start the data migration. Parse wanted me to paste the mongoDB connection URL which I had entered as "mongodb://localhost/". However, there was an error "no reachable servers". On my localhost, I am running the mongoDB using my terminal.

Any kind advise on this? This is my first time doing data migration and trying out mongoDB. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parse dashboard, go to App settings -> General. In this page you can find the "Export app data" button. Click and parse send you an email with the csv database data, use it for import your data in your local database (use rockmongo for example or [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/))

Comment: apology for the delayed reply, was busy lately. Yes, I am aware of the export data app data feature in the app settings. I tried and the data can only be exported in Json format.

Comment: the above might be a work around, however, i will also like to know why can't i used the mongodb URL link to export the data?

Comment: hi Dany, the above works as a good work around. Though i am still pretty interested to know why Mongodb connection URL can't work. Cheers

Comment: Your mongodb url can't work because parse can't access to your local mongo server. For export your data with mongodb connection, try to install mongodb on a server, and give the server url to parse. Cheers !